# find specific solution to intial value problem with derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a member fo the family that is a solution with conditions

$y=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}$ domain all real numbers with 
$y''-y=0$, $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$

I'm unsure what to do with the derivatives?

Answer (score 0):

with $y'=C_1e^{x}-C_2e^{-x}$ you will get $y'(0)=C_1-C_2=1$